# How to delete file in Java if locked by a process?

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, spring-boot

I decided to post a new question on this since none of the existing posts lead to me a solution. Mine is a Spring Boot application and here is the service:

```
public String fetchPrediction(MultipartFile file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File convFile = new File( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.setWritable(true);
        file.transferTo(convFile);
        INDArray array = new CustomerLossPrediction().generateOutput(convFile);
        Files.delete(Paths.get(convFile.getPath()));
        return array.toString();
    }
```

File deletion isn't happening and it gets stored at user home directory:
[image]

Found that the file is being used by the Java process. How can I delete this file once execution is completed? Is there a better approach here rather than writing to a file? Some of you would bring up writing to `OutputStream` here, but note that I need to work with `MultipartFile` in order to have file upload functionality.

Comment: How were you able to deduce that it's locked by the Java process?

Comment: Why not generate a temp convFile and mark the file as "deleteOnExit"? Seems convFile is only temporary from your code.

Comment: Printed down the exception first.
Had to close the spring servlet process to delete the file manually.

Comment: You should read the JDK doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- and check method "public void deleteOnExit()"

Comment: @Konrad
This time way better, but still there's `.tmp` file being created and unable to delete.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/517415/43357150-ce3d4a6a-929a-11e8-973c-454c5aea5887.png

Comment: Are you sure the CustomerLossPrediction class does not hold a stream to the file? I mentioned the "deleteOnExit" flag because of this. The file should be removed if the JVM exits.

Comment: Alright, I got you. I will try out few fixes at `CustomerLossPrediction` class. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @Konrad
Implemented temporary file creation in `CustomerLossPrediction` class too. But it doesnt change anything. Still temporary file is being created and unable to delete.

Comment: whats error you get?

Comment: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

Comment: Can you share the code for `generateOutput(File)`?

Comment: @Aris Newer versions of Windows directly show it in the error windows. On older versions of Windows you can use ProcessExplorer to find the culprit.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller
`generateOutput(File)` returns an N dimensional vector, basically the prediction result from the file.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if that's possible but I think you can rename the file to a randomly generated string then afterwards lock, read, unlock then delete the renamed file. In theory, another program could guess the filename and read the file just after it's unlocked but before it is deleted. But in practice, you'll probably be fine.